# Select Multiple allow only one selected for certain option

Tags: jquery, html

How to make certain part of options can be select multiple or only one. below is the Html

```
<div class="bootstrap-select active_select col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="cron_dow" data-style="btn btn-success" name="cron_dow" required multiple>

        //this 3 item can only be select only one, clear multiple selection if this any 3 item selected
        <option value="*" class="only_one">Every Weekdays</option>
        <option value="1,2,3,4,5" class="only_one">Monday - Friday</option>
        <option value="0,6" class="only_one">Weekends</option>

        //this 7 item can select multiple, clear above selection if selected
        <option value="1" title="Weekday: Monday" >Monday</option>
        <option value="2" title="Weekday: Tuesday" >Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3" title="Weekday: Wednesday" >Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4" title="Weekday: Thursday" >Thursday</option>
        <option value="5" title="Weekday: Friday" >Friday</option>
        <option value="6" title="Weekday: Saturday" >Saturday</option>
        <option value="0" title="Weekday: Sunday" >Sunday</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

there is duplicate post suggested to remove the multiple attribute.. that is not my case.. Top 3 (comment in code) is only can selected one, then it will clear any other selections. The other 7 Monday to Sunday can be multiple select..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on answer from @noobcode and @cumminUpp07... i came out of my own answer.. and its work..@noobcode work if i using only pure select option.. but im using bootstrap-selectpicker.. what to do is.. i just triggered the render option from bootstrap-select.. :) Thanks Guys..

and also `<select ..... multiple **size=7**>`  actually make it perfect..

```
$("select[name='cron_dow']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').hasClass('only_one')) {
        console.log("Up: " + $(this).val());
        jQuery("#cron_dow").removeAttr("multiple");
    } else {
        jQuery("#cron_dow").attr("multiple", "multiple");
        console.log("Down: " + $(this).val());
    }

    $('.cron_dow').selectpicker('render');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do some logic test to see if the last clicked was a `only_one` option and then unselect the rest, or unselect all `only_one` options if a non `only_one` option is selected here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tvL3em2f/  and the relevant code:

```
$('#cron_dow option').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('only_one')) {
        $('#cron_dow').val($(this).val());
    }
    else {
      $('option.only_one').prop('selected',false);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is giving only one value on top 3 option select and multiple select on last 7 options. Try this:-

Static value checking onchange but it works

```js
 $("select[name='cron_dow']").change(function(){
       console.log($(this).val());     
       if($(this).val() == "1,2,3,4,5" || $(this).val() == "*" ||  $(this).val() == "0,6" ){
       //console.log("sjdhsj");
        jQuery("#cron_dow").removeAttr("multiple");
       }
       else{
       //console.log('hello');
        jQuery("#cron_dow").attr("multiple","multiple");
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bootstrap-select active_select col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="cron_dow" data-style="btn btn-success" name="cron_dow" required multiple>

        //this 3 item can only be select only one, clear multiple selection if this any 3 item selected
        <option value="*" class="only_one">Every Weekdays</option>
        <option value="1,2,3,4,5" class="only_one">Monday - Friday</option>
        <option value="0,6" class="only_one">Weekends</option>

        //this 7 item can select multiple, clear above selection if selected
        <option value="1" title="Weekday: Monday" class="byy" >Monday</option>
        <option value="2" title="Weekday: Tuesday" class="byy" >Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3" title="Weekday: Wednesday" class="byy" >Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4" title="Weekday: Thursday" class="byy">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5" title="Weekday: Friday" class="byy">Friday</option>
        <option value="6" title="Weekday: Saturday" class="byy">Saturday</option>
        <option value="0" title="Weekday: Sunday" class="byy">Sunday</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting them in two select elements, where the first one doesn't have the multiple attribute

```html
   <select name="option1" required>
        <option value="*" class="only_one">Every Weekdays</option>
        <option value="1,2,3,4,5" class="only_one">Monday - Friday</option>
        <option value="0,6" class="only_one">Weekends</option>
    </select>    
    <select name="option2" required multiple>
        <option value="1" title="Weekday: Monday" >Monday</option>
        <option value="2" title="Weekday: Tuesday" >Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3" title="Weekday: Wednesday" >Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4" title="Weekday: Thursday" >Thursday</option>
        <option value="5" title="Weekday: Friday" >Friday</option>
        <option value="6" title="Weekday: Saturday" >Saturday</option>
        <option value="0" title="Weekday: Sunday" >Sunday</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the click event handler to each options and so take the right action:

```js
$('#cron_dow option').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is('.only_one')) {
        //
        // no more than 1 only_one selected
        //
        if ($('#cron_dow option.only_one:selected').length > 1) {
            $(this).prop('selected', false);
        }
        //
        // deselect the remaining
        //
        $('#cron_dow option:not(.only_one):selected').prop('selected', false);
    } else {
        //
        // deselect all the only_one options
        //
        $('#cron_dow option.only_one:selected').prop('selected', false);
    }
})
```

```css
select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="bootstrap-select active_select col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <select class="selectpicker" id="cron_dow" data-style="btn btn-success" name="cron_dow" required multiple size=10>

        //this 3 item can only be select only one, clear multiple selection if this any 3 item selected
        <option value="*" class="only_one">Every Weekdays</option>
        <option value="1,2,3,4,5" class="only_one">Monday - Friday</option>
        <option value="0,6" class="only_one">Weekends</option>

        //this 7 item can select multiple, clear above selection if selected
        <option value="1" title="Weekday: Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="2" title="Weekday: Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3" title="Weekday: Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4" title="Weekday: Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5" title="Weekday: Friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="6" title="Weekday: Saturday">Saturday</option>
        <option value="0" title="Weekday: Sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
</div>
```